# How do I understand the commas happening in join statements?

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I am running into a legendary code and have been struggling in breaking this down in more simpler terms. The legendary code runs perfectly. I am copying the join part of the code and not including the select for brevity. I extremely familiar with joins but I want to focus on two pieces

1.) What does `FROM COURSE c, GRADE g`  this try to achieve? How is it know how to do it?

2.) What does this do `GRADEITEM gs, STUDENT s, SECTION sec` when these tables are listed with commas after the inner join occured? Aren't I missing an on for these three tables tables?

```
FROM COURSE c, GRADE g 
INNER JOIN CEC cc 
ON g.SectionID = cc.SectionID AND g.StudentID = cc.StudentID, GRADEITEM gs, STUDENT s, SECTION sec
```

Comment: The commas correspond to the syntax of joins in 1989 (aka the old join syntax). In 1992 the `JOIN` clause was defined. I would advice never to mix old and new syntax. It's obscure and not all developers understand the consequences of mixing them. Stay clear of this mix.

Comment: “Legendary code“ i’m going to have to use that

Comment: @JohnWu I wish one day I'll write *legendary code*. ;-)

Comment: @JohnWu  I use legendary code in the sense that it's "very well known"  in our company, not necessarily with the great connotations LOL

Comment: I’m guessing the term you are looking for is “legacy code.”

Comment: Comma is cross join with lower precedence than keyword JOINs. PS Please: Before considering posting read the manual & google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. How comma acts is an SO faq. In code questions give a [mre]. Here that gives `select * from c , g inner join cc on g.SectionID = cc.SectionID` & googling re comma plus join gives that your unexpected behaviour is a SO faq. Ask 1 question. [ask] [help] [meta] [meta.se].

Answer (score 1):

This code:

```
FROM COURSE c,
     GRADE g INNER JOIN
     CEC cc 
     ON g.SectionID = cc.SectionID AND g.StudentID = cc.StudentID, GRADEITEM gs,
     STUDENT s,
     SECTION sec
```

is very arcane (which like "legendary" is a polite way of saying what I really think).

This is equivalent to:

```
FROM COURSE c
     GRADE g
     ON g.StudentID = cc.StudentID INNER JOIN
     CEC cc 
     ON g.SectionID = cc.SectionID CROSS JOIN
     GRADEITEM gs CROSS JOIN
     STUDENT s CROSS JOIN
     SECTION sec
```

The comma basically means `CROSS JOIN`.  I rewrite the first `CROSS JOIN` to be the intended `JOIN` by splitting the `ON` clause.

The rest are just Cartesian products.  I imagine that the `WHERE` clause provides more filtering.

"Arcane" and "archaic" are polite ways of describing the code.  This is very poorly written code.  If Cartesian products are intended, then `CROSS JOIN` is appropriate.  That said, I'm pretty sure that `JOIN`s are intended for all the tables -- for any useful query.

Comment: I should replace Legendary with Legacy code to give the appropriate sentiment. I define this legendary ask having the element of being very memorable for my team, not really with the great element in mind lol. Does the cross join occur with only columns having the exact spellings in the columns?

Comment: @Brandon . . . A `cross join` does not refer to columns.  It is a Cartesian product so it matches every row in one table with every row in the other.  Note:  Native English speakers know that "legendary" isn't quite what you meant.  I am guessing that all are amused by the use of the word; it is quite original.